# Bundler error whilst trying to install Varying Vagrant Vagrants and Vagrant plug-ins

Tags: vagrant, vvv-wordpress

I am new to Vagrant, Laraval, and Varying Vagrant Vagrants. I am attempting to get this environment installed and operational. I am on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

I am following the instructions posted [here](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/).

**Step 1** is install VirtualBox 5.0.x. Done that.

**Step 2** is install Vagrant 1.8.5. Done that.

After installing Vagrant with the pgk file I downloaded... I created a directory at `~/vagrant`. In that directory I did a `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64` command. I then `vagrant up`.

**Step 3** Install the `vagrant-hostsupdater` plugin with `vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater`

When I try to do this, I get the following error:

> Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
>   reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
>   caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
>   issues. The error from Bundler is:
>
> There was an error while trying to write to
>   `/Users/jonathan/.bundle/cache/compact_index/gems.hashicorp.com.443.68db9b3ad4be8461ccdecca2ae96d12a`.
>   It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
>
> Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using
>   `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may
>   result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a
>   block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To
>   upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config
>   disable_multisource true`.

Just to see if it made any difference, I changed the permissions on that file to `777`. The same error occurs though.

I also get this error if I try to install any of the other plugins mentioned in the instructions on the VVV site.

I have no idea why this occurs, or what to do about it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you run any `bundle` command with root (`sudo`) before ? make sure all folders under `/Users/jonathan/.bundle`(including `.bundle`) are owned by your user and not root

Comment: I've not used sudo at all with bundle. This is the first time I am installing these things, and sudo has never been required. I'll check on the ownership of those files. I did, however, need to use sudo to set the permissions on that file to 777,during my attempt to troubleshoot the issue. So that suggests it's not owned by my user.

Comment: run `ls -lR` to check ownership of the files/folder within .bundle and make sure you own the file

Comment: Thanks Frédéric. All files have `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff` — so it would seem I am not the owner. So this brings me to question, What installed that bundle folder? Is it installed when I installed Ruby, or something else? I generally use Homebrew to install such things, whenever possible. But Homebrew doesn't have root access, so that doesn't make sense either. Should I recursively change the owner to my username?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't know the original cause of the issue, the came to light through my discussion (in comments) with Frédéric Henri.

For some reason the permissions on the `~/.bundle` file had the owner set to `root`.

This was preventing the Vagrant plug-ins from installing. To correct this issue I changed the owner to my username.

From the home folder (`cd ~/`) use the following command, `sudo chown -R <USERNAME>:staff ~/.bundle`

This resolved the issue.